# map array inside map array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to iterate over an array that is inside of a JSON object:

```
get('users', users => {
  users.map(({ titles }) => {
    titles.map(title => {
      console.log(title)
  }))
  })
})
```

But when I use map on the array it throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

When just logging `titles` they get listed in the console.

I've tried getting the length too, but it still returns the same error.

Why cant i use regular array methods on `titles`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including how `get` is defined and what the value passed for `users` will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special about this. Either `users` is undefined or at least one `user.titles` is. You might dodge this by setting a default empty array for titles:

`({titles = []}) => titles.map(...)`

Comment: Wow. One of the titles was missing in db. Thanks for the fast reply!